# php function returns empty string. echo prints the string properly;

Tags: php

I am completely stumped on what appears to be a trivial problem.

I have this function:

```
function findCategoryNameInTree($id, $tree) {
    foreach($tree as $branch) {
        if ($branch['category_id'] == $id) {
             echo $branch['name'];//works
             print_r($branch['name']);//works
             //return($branch['name']); //returns nothing
             return $branch['name'];//fix this line per feedback still no return value
        } else {
            if(count($branch['children']) > 0) {
                findCategoryNameInTree($id,$branch['children']);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why it's not returning anything.

Please help!

**Edit**
Here's how I call my function

```
//what I really want to do
$primgenre = findCategoryNameInTree($cat_id,$category_tree['children']);

//but this doesnt work either
echo $primgenre;

//nor this
print_r($pringenre);
```

Comment: You didn't show us the piece of the code that calls your `findCategoryNameInTree` function and how is it that you determine that function's return value is something that's wrong and not your interpretation of function's return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to return for this :-

```
findCategoryNameInTree($id,$branch['children']);
```

Change :-

```
return findCategoryNameInTree($id,$branch['children']);
```

Comment: Unbelievable, cant believe I missed that. Thank you so much! My code works with or without the parentheses everyone else suggested was the problem. -3 all for that.

Comment: if you want get -1, then ask more question like this. to get +1, your question has to be understandable

Comment: Didn't realize my question was unclear. Looking at it again I guess I didn't actually ASK anything. Thanks for the tip. Too much of a rush I guess.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) clearly mentioned

> When returning an array, you should declare the array before the
>   return, else the result is not as you expect;

Also see the **NOTE**

> You should never use parentheses around your return variable when
>   returning by reference, as this will not work. You can only return
>   variables by reference, not the result of a statement.

```
foreach($tree as $branch) { }
```

here `$branch` is just an internal pointer of array ( assume as reference ) of `$tree`.

Comment: I'm not returning an array $branch['name'] is a string; Also, I removed the parentheses and I'm still getting an empty return value;

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the round brackets, and then it should work!?

```
return $branch['name'];
```

Thanks for the minus ;)

If your function works as to the point you say, calling

```
$test = findCategoryNameInTree(XY, "bla");
echo $test;
```

should output something.

Comment: Matters when you return by reference, so it's best to always leave it off.

Comment: I fixed this and it still returns no value; Any other ideas?

Comment: Didn't give you the minus btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findCategoryNameInTree($id, $tree) {
foreach($tree as $branch) {
    if ($branch['category_id'] == $id) {
         x = $branch['name']; 
    } else {
        if(count($branch['children']) > 0) {
            findCategoryNameInTree($id,$branch['children']);
        }
    }

}
return x;
```

}

Comment: There's no reason you can't have the `return` within the `foreach` loop. In fact, it's better to have it in the loop because you don't have to wait for the loop to finish in order to return the desired value.

Comment: I tested the code and it works for me with all things i could imagine like you do the return, like I do with a break in the foreach and then return ...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, also the $my_result way!

```
<?php

$tree = ARRAY();
$tree[0] = ARRAY('category_id'=>10, 'name'=>'ten', 'children'=>'');
$tree[1] = ARRAY('category_id'=>11, 'name'=>'eleven', 'children'=>'');
$tree[2] = ARRAY('category_id'=>12, 'name'=>'twelve', 'children'=>'');


function findCategoryNameInTree($id, $tree) {
  //$my_result = 'none';
  foreach($tree as $branch) {
    if ($branch['category_id'] === $id) {
      //echo $branch['name'];//works
      //print_r($branch['name']);//works
      //$my_result = $branch['name'];
      //break; 
      return $branch['name']; //returns nothing
    }
    //else {
    // if(count($branch['children']) > 0) {
    //    findCategoryNameInTree($id,$branch['children']);
    //  }
    //}
  }
  //return $my_result;
}

echo findCategoryNameInTree(10, $tree).'<br />';
echo findCategoryNameInTree(11, $tree).'<br />';
echo findCategoryNameInTree(12, $tree).'<br />';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$primgenre = findCategoryNameInTree($cat_id,$category_tree);
```

$branch is (should be) an array, so $tree is (should be). If $tree array contains well-formed $branch arrays everything should work fine. See my other solution with my example $tree array.